# Is there any use case for `sed -n "/regexp/p"` in a world where grep exists?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, grep

`sed -n "/regexp/p"` will print only lines that match `regexp` and no other.  This seems exactly equivalent to what `grep` does.  The only use case I see to use this construct instead of `grep` is if you're already doing something inside of sed and piping to another program would be unwieldly.

Can anyone think of other reasons why they would use this construct over `grep`?

Comment: see, why do we have the word "hi ya", if we can wave. Because reducing a language to only have what is absolutely needed, to write the programs that we think are necessary, will result in a language that is un-usable.

Comment: I simply guess that powerful tools have intersections. You can also reproduce the same behavior with awk.

Comment: `sed` ciould use start and end *addresses* and permit a lot of things: try this: `seq 1 200000 | sed -ne '/^100000$/,/^15/{/\(34\).*\1/p}'` then think about!

Answer (score 4):

The command `sed -n '/re/p'` (or `sed '/re/!d'`, without using `-n` to suppress the default output at the end of each cycle) is identical to `grep -e 're'`, and both can be traced back to the `ed` editor's `g/re/p` command ("globally match `re` and print"); using `sed` and `grep` in a basic way like this is like running a `g` command over a text in `ed`.

If all you want to do is to print the lines that matches a particular regular expression, use `grep`.  This is what `grep` does.  It's its most basic task. It would make your shell code cleaner and easier to understand and to maintain if you used `grep` rather than `sed` for this task.

Use `/re/p` in `sed` if it's part of some longer `sed` editing script. Don't pipe `grep` into `sed` or the other way around, unless you have some really particular and quirky requirements.

Note that the `/re/` in the `sed` command is an *address*.  It addresses all the lines that matches the particular regular expression.  With `/re/p`, it prints those lines. In other words, `/re/` is the address for the `p` command.

Addresses can be line numbers too, or a range described by two line numbers, two regular expressions, or a combination thereof.  So you could, for example, use `sed -n '5,/re/p'` to print all lines from line 5 to whatever line matches `re`.  The `grep` utility doesn't have this ability, which `sed` inherited from the `ed` editor.

In summary: `grep` is the more appropriate tool for just extracting the lines matching a particular regular expression.  To extract lines matching more complex criteria (e.g. within some range), use `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: @hawk That p is the print command, not an option. The preceding regular expression is the address for the p command. Each line that matches the expression will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the size:

```
$ ls -lh /bin/grep /bin/sed
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 207K Apr 29  2016 /bin/grep
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  72K Feb 11  2016 /bin/sed
$
```

`grep` uses more memory than `sed`

And the execution time (real):

```
$ time date | grep Apr
Fri Apr 17 13:31:11 PDT 2020

real    0m0.035s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.016s
$ time date | sed -n '/Apr/p'
Fri Apr 17 13:31:29 PDT 2020

real    0m0.028s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.016s
$
```

See how `sed` is a little bit faster?

In an embedded environment which is resource constrained, that may matter.

Comment: The size difference doesn't say much, and besides, it will heavily depend on what system you're on. On my machine, `sed` is 44096 bytes while `grep` is 41512 bytes.

Comment: Trying to analyze application performance from a single execution using trivial data is full of errors. Run each 1024 times; use a much bigger file;put the target near the End-of-File.